Update variables in ContentView at midnight
I have the following variables in my ContentView file
let DOY = getDayOfYear()
let DRNoW = daysinyear()
let WN = weekNumber()
let DN = dayNumber()

And using the func of:
func getDayOfYear() -> Int {
    let date = Date() // now
    let cal = Calendar.current
    let day1 = cal.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: date)!

    return day1
}

I want the variables to update at midnight in the ContentView.
How do I make it happen?

You could subcribe to NSCalendarDayChanged
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ...
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: NSNotification.Name.NSCalendarDayChanged)) { (output) in
            // Update variables at midnight here
        }
    }
}


This is a MacOS app. UIKit isn't available. NSCalendarDayChanged is available. How can I make it work?

@Misfit I have updated answer

In the event this works; Where do i send a tip?

You just to upvote and mark my answer is accepted answer bro

hmm... Maybe i missed something? i put: DOY = getDayofYear()  in the // Update variables at midnight here. and it didn't work. What did i do wrong there?

You should change Calendar timezone to your timezone too

i think, it has to be a class @Published to work. Will try again tonight.

You can change your time in computer to test too bro

would doing this:   Text("(DOY)") \ cause problems for this to work?

You should mark DOY with @State and update DOY value when closure get called

This question, answers how to schedule the notification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486370/nscalendardaychanged-only-observed-when-app-is-in-foreground
